# TypeError: Cannot read property 'SDK_VERSION' of undefined

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

I already have a firebase functions project setup in some folder in my computer but was trying to set it up somewhere else. When doing that, it happens to mess up something somewhere and i now get that error when deploying my functions using `firebase deploy` :

```
functions@ build C:\Users\bertr\Documents\GitHub\GreenplayFirebaseFunctions\functions
> tsc

+  functions: Finished running predeploy script.
i  functions: ensuring required API cloudfunctions.googleapis.com is enabled...
i  functions: ensuring required API cloudbuild.googleapis.com is enabled...
+  functions: required API cloudbuild.googleapis.com is enabled
+  functions: required API cloudfunctions.googleapis.com is enabled

Error: Error occurred while parsing your function triggers.

TypeError: Cannot read property 'SDK_VERSION' of undefined
    at registerDatabase (C:\Users\bertr\Documents\GitHub\GreenplayFirebaseFunctions\functions\node_modules\@firebase\database\dist\index.node.cjs.js:15610:28)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\bertr\Documents\GitHub\GreenplayFirebaseFunctions\functions\node_modules\@firebase\database\dist\index.node.cjs.js:15645:5)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1072:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1101:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:937:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:12)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:961:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:92:18)
    at FirebaseNamespace.get (C:\Users\bertr\Documents\GitHub\GreenplayFirebaseFunctions\functions\node_modules\firebase-admin\lib\firebase-namespace.js:259:38)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\bertr\Documents\GitHub\GreenplayFirebaseFunctions\functions\lib\firebase\firebase.js:13:20)
```

Tried to upgrade firebase-tools, reinstalling firebase, setup account again but i still get that error. Maybe that has a link to firebase SDK V8 and 9 but i'm not sure... I did'nt change anything  in my code.

here's my firebase.json file :

```
{
  "functions": {
    "predeploy": "npm --prefix \"$RESOURCE_DIR\" run build",
    "source": "functions"
  },
  "emulators": {
    "functions": {
      "port": 8201
    },
    "firestore": {
      "port": 9288
    },
    "database": {
      "port": 6120
    },
    "ui": {
      "enabled": true
    }
  }
}
```

and my package.json file :

```
{
  "name": "functions",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "tsc",
    "serve": "npm run build && firebase emulators:start --import ../../database",
    "shell": "npm run build && firebase functions:shell",
    "start": "npm run shell",
    "deploy": "npm run build && firebase deploy --only functions",
    "logs": "firebase functions:log",
    "test": "mocha -r ts-node/register tests/**/*.test.ts"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "10"
  },
  "main": "lib/index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "firebase-admin": "^9.4.2",
    "firebase-functions": "^3.13.0",
    "geofire-common": "^5.2.0",
    "geolib": "^3.3.1",
    "moment-timezone": "^0.5.32",
    "tmp": "^0.2.1",
    "xlsx": "^0.17.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/chai": "^4.2.18",
    "@types/mocha": "^8.2.2",
    "@types/tmp": "^0.2.1",
    "chai": "^4.3.4",
    "firebase-functions-test": "^0.2.0",
    "mocha": "^9.0.0",
    "ts-node": "^9.0.0",
    "typescript": "^3.8.0"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

Thanks a lot guys!

Comment: Try updating your Firebase-tools to the latest version by running: `firebase i -g firebase-tools`. Additionally, refer to the [Firebase Release Notes](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/js) for the updates.

Comment: @RJC you mean `npm i -g firebase-tools` ? but anyway, it does not change anything :(

Answer (score 2):

Turns out i needed to update firebase-admin to latest version inside functions folder..

```
npm i firebase-admin
```

works for me!

Comment: Btw, you need to add @latest to the end of it. Here's what worked for me:
`npm install --save firebase-functions@latest firebase-admin@latest` (I needed to upgrade both)